# Other than gelatin what makes gummy bears chewy?

Tags: substitutions, candy, gelatin

From previous experiences, every time I try to make gummy bears they are more springy than chewy like gummies are supposed to be. I have been wondering, other than gelatin, what makes gummy bears chewy? I use 250 bloom gelatin powder.

Comment: If you could post the actual recipe you're using I'm sure it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

From a package:

> corn syrup, sucrose, gelatin, citric acid, apple juice concentrate, sodium citrate,
>       coconut oil, natural and artificial flavors, carnauba wax, red 40, yellow 5, blue 1

Likely the sugar types and their ratio is important. pH (citrate) shouldn't make a lot of difference unless you're using something weird instead of apple juice. Carnauba wax is likely a mold release agent, which leaves coconut oil as the most mysterious ingredient. I wouldn't bet on it affecting chewiness much, but these dense gel recipes can be pretty sensitive to minor ingredients.

Comment: I agree it's likely the sugars. I make my gummies with just juice and gelatin which is a much, much lower density of sugar than commercial gummy bears and I get the squeaky/springy texture that the OP describes.

Experimenting with corn syrup and more sugar generally will likely get you closer to you the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

One gummy bear hacker says you need to leave them out for 3 days to aerate for the gelatin to toughen up. The longer you leave them out, the chewier they become.
https://topsecretrecipes.com/foodhackerblog/haribo-gold-bears-gummy-candy/

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your ingredients are wrong, a wrong process is the more likely culprit.

Gummi bears are traditionally make gummylike with gelatine, nothing else. But what you describe as "springy" gelatine reminds me of the way gelatine becomes in its usual application for producing pie fillings and other desserts meant to eat with a spoon or fork.

Gummy bears are much drier than these desserts. I don't know if they make them that way by using more concentrated gelatine, by drying them out somehow, or both. But I think this is the main difference to a "classic" gelatine recipe. And as Wayfaring stranger mentioned, there are no other gelling agents in the mix of commercial gummy bears either.

Comment: Gummy bears are 6-10% gelatin. Gelatin desserts run 2-5%.

Answer (score 0):

Gelatine is not always used as some of these types of sweets are vegan or Halal and they cannot use Gelatine for “moral” or religious reasons.Carnuba wax or agar agar or Guar gum are often used instead.Gelatine is an animal by-product so is not vegetarian.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).